# How to install "gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf" specific version?

Tags: 20.04, arm, cross-compilation

Am performing cross compilation on x86 and target platform is armhf. When i run command
`apt-get install -y gcc-arm-linux* g++-arm-linux*`,  It installs **4.11.2.0** version and output is as below

```
g++-arm-linux-gnueabi is already the newest version (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1). 
g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf is already the newest version (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1).    
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi is already the newest version (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1).    
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf is already the newest version (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1)
```

But i need **4.9.3.0** version. How to install 4.9.3.0 version in ubuntu command line??

Am using ubuntu 20.04 and performing cross compilation using focal apt list

my /etc/apt.source.list file is as below

```
echo "### Copying ARM sources to /etc/apt/sources.list ###"
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe" >  /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main universe" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Output of `apt policy gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`

```
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf:
  Installed: 4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please include the output of `apt policy gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` in your question

Comment: Added output in the question

Comment: So I don't see any repository associated with the 11.2.0-1ubuntu1 version - did you install it manually from a .deb file?

Answer (score 1):

You can force a version:

```
apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf=4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2
```

From `man apt-get`: `install pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But before installing this i need to install "cpp-arm-linux-gnueabihf=4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2", since this is dependency for `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf=4.9.3.0`.